# Find matrix $T$ relative to standard basis

Tags: linear-algebra

> **problem**:
>
> A linear transformation $T$ rotates each vector in $\Bbb R^2 $ clockwise through $90$ degree
>
> Find matrix $T$ relative to standard basis$
>         \begin{bmatrix}
>         1  \\
>         0  \\
>          \end{bmatrix}
> $,
>   $
>         \begin{bmatrix}
>         0  \\
>         1 \\
>          \end{bmatrix}
> $
>
> **Solution**: Here value of linear transformation is not given
>
> like $T(a,b)=(a,0)$

I don't know "how to solve such question"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since we have

$$T\begin{bmatrix}
        1  \\
        0  \\
         \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
        0  \\
        -1  \\
         \end{bmatrix}\quad\text{and}\quad T\begin{bmatrix}
        0  \\
        1  \\
         \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
        1  \\
        0  \\
         \end{bmatrix}$$
so the matrix of $T$ in the standard basis  is
$$\begin{bmatrix}
        0&1 \\
        -1&0  \\
         \end{bmatrix}$$